# Shopping Cart List/Dictionaries Problems

Tags: python, list, dictionary, menu

I encountered some problems and am confused whether it is caused by my dictionaries or lists.
From line 230 onwards, there problems.
1)How to show the price after adding the items?
2)The 'remove codes' has problems due to list or dictionary
3)Checkout also has problem due to list or dictionary

```
def mainMenu():
    while True:
        selection = input('''
    
                    --- SHOPPING MENU ---
    
    Select a number for the action you would like to do
    
    1. Check shop
    2. Check shopping list
    3. Check-out
    4. Leave
    
    Choice: ''')

    if selection == '1':
        checkShop()
    elif selection == '2':
        if len(Shopping_List2) == 0:
            print(
                '\nYour shopping list is currently empty, please find what items are available and add them by pressing 1.')
        else:
            displayList()
    elif selection == '3':
        checkout()
    elif selection == '4':
        print('Goodbye! Hope to see you again soon!')
        break
    else:
        print('\n       You did not make a valid selection, please try again')


ShoppingItems = {'D1': ['Milk', 2.30], 'D2': ['Butter', 4.50], 'D3': ['Eggs', 3.40], 'D4': ['Cheese slices', 3.15],
             'D5': ['Evaporated milk creamer', 1.40], 'D6': ['Milo', 12.50], 'D7': ['Biscuits', 5.30],
             'D8': ['Yogurt', 0.95],
             'P1': ['Bread', 2.70], 'P2': ['Cereal', 7.00], 'P3': ['Crackers', 3.10], 'P4': ['Chips', 2.60],
             'P5': ['Raisin', 2.10], 'P6': ['Nuts', 2.00], 'P7': ['Green bean', 1.05], 'P8': ['Barley', 1.05],
             'C1': ['Tomato', 1.45], 'C2': ['Button mushroom', 1.15], 'C3': ['Baking bean', 1.35],
             'C4': ['Tuna fish', 1.45], 'C5': ['Kernel corn', 1.25], 'C6': ['Sardine fish', 1.10],
             'C7': ['Chicken luncheon meat', 1.95], 'C8': ['Pickled lettuce', 0.95],
             'S1': ['Fine Salt', 0.80], 'S2': ['Sea Salt Flakes', 1.30], 'S3': ['Chicken Stock', 3.15],
             'S4': ['Chilli Sauce', 2.65], 'S5': ['Oyster Sauce', 4.50], 'S6': ['Sweet Soy Sauce', 3.75],
             'S7': ['Tomato Ketchup', 3.20], 'S8': ['Sesame Oil', 4.95],
             'B1': ['Green Tea Canned 330 ML', 15.00], 'B2': ['Blackcurrant Ribena 330 ML', 31.00],
             'B3': ['100 Plus 24 Cans', 15.00], 'B4': ['Orange Cordial 2 Litre', 3.90],
             'B5': ['Mineral Water 24 x 600 ML', 7.00], 'B6': ['Pineapple juice', 9.90],
             'B7': ['Nescafe Coffee', 9.90], 'B8': ['Coke 24 Cans', 12.40]}


# shopping_list = []

def print_item(c):
    for i in c:
        print('%10s %s $%.2f' % (i, c[i][0], c[i][1]))


def checkShop():
    while True:
        choices = input('''
                  --- SHOPPING ITEMS ---
    
    How would you like the shopping items to be arranged by?
    
    Categories:
    Dairy | Packaged Goods | Canned Goods | Condiments/Sauces | Drink & Beverages
    
    1. Category
    2. Alphabetical order
    3. Ascending value order
    4. Return

    Choice: ''')

    if choices == '1':
        print('''
                      Dairy                        Packaged Goods                      Canned Goods                     Condiments/Sauces                       Drink & Beverages
    D1: Milk                        $2.30   | P1: Bread         $2.70   | C1: Tomato                    $1.45   | S1: Fine Salt         $0.80   | B1: Green Tea Canned 330ML        $15.00  |
    D2: Butter                      $4.50   | P2: Cereal        $7.00   | C2: Button Mushroom           $1.15   | S2: Sea Salt Flakes   $1.30   | B2: Blackcurrant Ribena 330ML     $31.00  |
    D3: Eggs                        $3.40   | P3: Crackers      $3.10   | C3: Baking Bean               $1.35   | S3: Chicken Stock     $3.15   | B3: 100 Plus 24 Cans              $15.00  |
    D4: Cheese Slices               $3.15   | P4: Chips         $2.60   | C4: Tuna Fish                 $1.45   | S4: Chili Sauce       $2.65   | B4: Orange Cordial 2 Litre        $3.90   |
    D5: Evaporated Milk Creamer     $1.40   | P5: Raisin        $2.10   | C5: Kernel Corn               $1.25   | S5: Oyster Sauce      $4.50   | B5: Mineral Water 24 x 600 ML     $7.00   |
    D6: Milo                        $12.50  | P6: Nuts          $2.00   | C6: Sardine Fish              $1.10   | S6: Sweet Soy Sauce   $3.75   | B6: Pineapple Juice               $0.80   |
    D7: Biscuits                    $5.30   | P7: Green Bean    $1.05   | C7: Chicken Luncheon Meat     $1.95   | S7: Tomato Ketchup    $3.20   | B7: Nescafe Coffee                $9.90   |
    D8: Yogurt                      $0.95   | P8: Barley        $1.05   | C8: Pickled Lettuce           $0.95   | S8: Sesame Oil        $4.95   | B8: Coke 24 Cans                  $12.40  |
        ''')
        ItemChoices()
    elif choices == '2':
        choicesA = input('''
    1. By each category
    2. By all categories
    3. Return
    
    Choice: ''')
        if choicesA == '1':
            print('''
                      Dairy                        Packaged Goods                      Canned Goods                     Condiments/Sauces                       Drink & Beverages
    D7: Biscuits                    $5.30   | P8: Barley        $1.05   | C3: Baking Bean               $1.35   | S3: Chicken Stock     $3.15   | B3: 100 Plus 24 Cans              $15.00  |
    D2: Butter                      $4.50   | P1: Bread         $2.70   | C2: Button Mushroom           $1.15   | S4: Chili Sauce       $2.65   | B2: Blackcurrant Ribena 330ML     $31.00  |
    D4: Cheese Slices               $3.15   | P2: Cereal        $7.00   | C7: Chicken Luncheon Meat     $1.95   | S1: Fine Salt         $0.80   | B8: Coke 24 Cans                  $12.40  |
    D3: Eggs                        $3.40   | P4: Chips         $2.60   | C5: Kernel Corn               $1.25   | S5: Oyster Sauce      $4.50   | B1: Green Tea Canned 330ML        $15.00  |
    D5: Evaporated Milk Creamer     $1.40   | P3: Crackers      $3.10   | C8: Pickled Lettuce           $0.95   | S2: Sea Salt Flakes   $1.30   | B5: Mineral Water 24 x 600 ML     $7.00   |
    D1: Milk                        $2.30   | P7: Green Bean    $1.05   | C6: Sardine Fish              $1.10   | S8: Sesame Oil        $4.95   | B7: Nescafe Coffee                $9.90   |
    D6: Milo                        $12.50  | P6: Nuts          $2.00   | C1: Tomato                    $1.45   | S6: Sweet Soy Sauce   $3.75   | B4: Orange Cordial 2 Litre        $3.90   |
    D8: Yogurt                      $0.95   | P5: Raisin        $2.10   | C4: Tuna Fish                 $1.45   | S7: Tomato Ketchup    $3.20   | B6: Pineapple Juice               $0.80   |
            ''')
            ItemChoices()
        elif choicesA == '2':
            print('''
                                                                                            ---ALPHABETICAL ORDER---
    B3: 100 Plus 24 Cans            $15.00  | P2: Cereal                    $7.00   | D3: Eggs                      $3.40   | B5: Mineral Water 24 x 600 ML     $7.00   | C6: Sardine Fish      $1.10   |
    C3: Baking Bean                 $1.35   | D4: Cheese Slices             $3.15   | D5: Evaporated Milk Creamer   $1.40   | B7: Nescafe Coffee                $9.90   | S2: Sea Salt Flakes   $1.39   |
    P8: Barley                      $1.05   | C7: Chicken Luncheon Meat     $1.95   | S1: Fine Salt                 $0.80   | P6: Nuts                          $2.00   | S8: Sesame Oil        $4.95   |
    D7: Biscuits                    $5.30   | S3: Chicken Stock             $3.15   | P7: Green Bean                $1.05   | B4: Orange Cordial 2 Litre        $3.90   | S6: Sweet Soy Sauce   $3.75   |
    B2: Blackcurrant Ribena 330ML   $31.00  | S4: Chili Sauce               $2.65   | B1: Green Tea Canned 330ML    $15.00  | S5: Oyster Sauce                  $4.50   | C1: Tomato            $1.45   |
    P1: Bread                       $2.70   | P4: Chips                     $2.60   | C5: Kernel Corn               $1.25   | C8: Pickled Lettuce               $0.95   | S7: Tomato Ketchup    $3.20   |
    D2: Butter                      $4.50   | B8: Coke 24 Cans              $12.40  | D1: Milk                      $2.30   | B6: Pineapple Juice               $0.80   | C4: Tuna Fish         $1.45   |
    C2: Button Mushroom             $1.15   | P3: Crackers                  $3.10   | D6: Milo                      $0.95   | P5: Raisin                        $2.10   | D8: Yogurt            $0.95   |
            ''')
            ItemChoices()
        elif choicesA == '3':
            return
        else:
            print('\n       You did not make a valid selection, please try again')

    elif choices == '3':
        choicesP = input('''
    1. By each category
    2. By all categories
    3. Return
    
    Choice: ''')
        if choicesP == '1':
            print('''
            
                      Dairy                        Packaged Goods                      Canned Goods                     Condiments/Sauces                       Drink & Beverages
    D8: Yogurt                      $0.95   | P8: Barley        $1.05   | C8: Pickled Lettuce           $0.95   | S1: Fine Salt         $0.80   | B6: Pineapple Juice               $0.90   |
    D5: Evaporated Milk Creamer     $1.40   | P7: Green Bean    $1.05   | C6: Sardine Fish              $1.10   | S2: Sea Salt Flakes   $1.30   | B4: Orange Cordial 2 Litre        $3.90   |
    D1: Milk                        $2.30   | P6: Nuts          $2.00   | C2: Button Mushroom           $1.15   | S4: Chili Sauce       $2.65   | B5: Mineral Water 24 x 600 ML     $7.00   |
    D4: Cheese slices               $3.15   | P5: Raisin        $2.10   | C5: Kernel Corn               $1.25   | S3: Chicken Stock     $3.15   | B7: Nescafe Coffee                $9.90   |
    D3: Eggs                        $3.40   | P4: Chips         $2.60   | C3: Baking Bean               $1.35   | S7: Tomato Ketchup    $3.20   | B8: Coke 24 Cans                  $12.40  |
    D2: Butter                      $4.50   | P1: Bread         $2.70   | C1: Tomato                    $1.45   | S6: Sweet Soy Sauce   $3.75   | B3: 100 Plus 24 Cans              $15.00  |
    D7: Biscuits                    $5.30   | P3: Crackers      $3.10   | C4: Tuna Fish                 $1.45   | S5: Oyster Sauce      $4.50   | B1: Green Tea Canned 330ML        $15.00  |
    D6: Milo                        $12.50  | P2: Cereal        $7.00   | C7: Chicken Luncheon Meat     $1.95   | S8: Sesame Oil        $4.95   | B2: Blackcurrant Ribena 330ML     $31.00  |
            ''')
            ItemChoices()
        elif choicesP == '2':
            print('''

                                                                                                        ---ASCENDING VALUE ORDER---
    S1: Fine Salt           $0.80   | C5: Kernel Corn               $1.25   | P5: Raisin            $2.10   | S7: Tomato Ketchup            $3.20   | P2: Cereal                        $7.00   |
    B6: Pineapple Juice     $0.90   | S2: Sea Salt Flakes           $1.30   | D1: Milk              $2.30   | D3: Eggs                      $3.40   | B5: Mineral Water 24 x 600 ML     $7.00   |
    C8: Pickled Lettuce     $0.95   | C3: Baking Bean               $1.35   | P4: Chips             $2.60   | S6: Sweet Soy Sauce           $3.75   | B7: Nescafe Coffee                $9.90   |
    D8: Yogurt              $0.95   | D5: Evaporated Milk Creamer   $1.40   | S4: Chili Sauce       $2.65   | B4: Orange Cordial 2 Litre    $3.90   | B8: Coke 24 Cans                  $12.40  |
    P8: Barley              $1.05   | C1: Tomato                    $1.45   | P1: Bread             $2.70   | D2: Butter                    $4.50   | D6: Milo                          $12.50  |
    P7: Green Bean          $1.05   | C4: Tuna Fish                 $1.45   | P3: Crackers          $3.10   | S5: Oyster Sauce              $4.50   | B3: 100 Plus 24 Cans              $15.00  |
    C6: Sardine Fish        $1.10   | C7: Chicken Luncheon Meat     $1.95   | D4: Cheese Slices     $3.15   | S8: Sesame Oil                $4.95   | B1: Green Tea Canned 330ML        $15.00  |
    C2: Button Mushroom     $1.15   | P6: Nuts                      $2.00   | S3: Chicken Stock     $3.15   | D7: Biscuits                  $5.30   | B2: Blackcurrant Ribena 330ML     $31.00  |
            ''')
            ItemChoices()
        elif choicesP == '3':
            return
        else:
            print('\n       You did not make a valid selection, please try again')

    elif choices == '4':
        return
    else:
        print('\n       You did not make a valid selection, please try again')


def ItemChoices():
    ItemChoice = input('''
        Options for shopping list:
        1. Add item(s)
        2. View item(s)
        3. Remove item(s)
        4. Clear shopping list
        5. Go back to shop/menu 
    
    Choice: ''')

if ItemChoice == '1':
    addItem()
elif ItemChoice == '2':
    if len(Shopping_List2) == 0:
        print(
            '\nYour shopping list is currently empty, please add items to your shopping list by typing in the code next to the item.')
    else:
        displayList()
elif ItemChoice == '3':
    removeItem()

elif ItemChoice == '4':
    ClearItems = input('''
    Clear items:    
    1. Clear certain items
    2. Fully clear items
    3. Leave
    
    Choice: ''')
    if ClearItems == '1':
        # ClearListCI
        print('test')
    elif ClearItems == '2':
        clearListFully()
    elif ClearItems == '3':
        return
    else:
        print('\n       You did not make a valid selection, please try again')
elif ItemChoice == '5':
    ReturnTo = input('''
    Return to:
    1. Shop
    2. Item Options
    3. Main Menu
    
    Choice: ''')
    if ReturnTo == '1':
        return checkShop()
    elif ReturnTo == '2':
        return ItemChoices()
    elif ReturnTo == '3':
        return mainMenu()
    else:
        print('\n       You did not make a valid selection, please try again')
else:
    print('\n       You did not make a valid selection, please try again')


# Non-nested list
Shopping_List1 = []

# Nested List
Shopping_List2 = []


def displayList():
    SL1 = Shopping_List1[::2]
    print('\nYour items:', *SL1, sep='\n- ')
    print('\nItem(s) in shopping list:', len(Shopping_List2))


def addItem():
    while True:
        item = input('\n Enter the item code you wish to add to the shopping list (e.g. D1 to add item Milk): ')
        if ShoppingItems.get(item) is not None:
            ShoppingItemsWant = ShoppingItems.get(item)
            Shopping_add1 = []
            Shopping_add2 = []
            Shopping_add1.extend(ShoppingItemsWant)
            Shopping_add2.append(ShoppingItemsWant)
        
        print('\n Item has been added to shopping list:', Shopping_add1[0])
        moreI = input('''
    Add more item options:
    1. Add more of the same item
    2. Add other items
    3. View items
    4. Return (That's all of the items)
    Choice: ''')

        if moreI == '1':
            moreIA = int(input('\nInsert how many more of the item you would like to add to the shopping list: '))
            Shopping_add1.extend(ShoppingItemsWant * moreIA)
            TSA2 = (Shopping_add2 * moreIA)
            Shopping_add2.extend(TSA2)
            print(moreIA, 'more of this item has been added to the shopping list:', Shopping_add1[0])
            moreIA2 = input('''
    Add more item options:
    1. Add other items
    2. View items
    3. Return (That's all of the items)
    
    Choice: ''')
            if moreIA2 == '1':
                Shopping_List1.extend(Shopping_add1)
                Shopping_List2.extend(Shopping_add2)
                return addItem()
            elif moreIA2 == '2':
                Shopping_List1.extend(Shopping_add1)
                Shopping_List2.extend(Shopping_add2)
                displayList()
                moreIA5 = input('''
    Return to:
    1. Shop
    2. Item options     
    3. Main menu
            
    Choice: ''')

                if moreIA5 == '1':
                    return checkShop()
                elif moreIA5 == '2':
                    return ItemChoices()
                elif moreIA5 == '3':
                    return mainMenu()
                else:
                    print('\n       You did not make a valid selection, please try again')

            elif moreIA2 == '3':
                Shopping_List1.extend(Shopping_add1)
                Shopping_List2.extend(Shopping_add2)
                moreIA4 = input('''
    Return to:
    1. Shop
    2. Item options     
    3. Main menu
            
    Choice: ''')

                if moreIA4 == '1':
                    return checkShop()
                elif moreIA4 == '2':
                    return ItemChoices()
                elif moreIA4 == '3':
                    return mainMenu()
                else:
                    print('\n       You did not make a valid selection, please try again')

        elif moreI == '2':
            Shopping_List1.extend(Shopping_add1)
            Shopping_List2.extend(Shopping_add2)

        elif moreI == '3':
            Shopping_List1.extend(Shopping_add1)
            Shopping_List2.extend(Shopping_add2)
            displayList()
            moreIA = input('''
    Return to:
    1. Shop
    2. Item options     
    3. Main menu
            
    Choice: ''')

            if moreIA == '1':
                return checkShop()
            elif moreIA == '2':
                return ItemChoices()
            elif moreIA == '3':
                return mainMenu()
            else:
                print('\n       You did not make a valid selection, please try again')

        elif moreI == '4':
            Shopping_List1.extend(Shopping_add1)
            Shopping_List2.extend(Shopping_add2)
            moreIA = input('''
    Return to:
    1. Shop
    2. Item options     
    3. Main menu        
            
    Choice: ''')

            if moreIA == '1':
                return checkShop()
            elif moreIA == '2':
                return ItemChoices()
            elif moreIA == '3':
                return mainMenu()
            else:
                print('\n       You did not make a valid selection, please try again')
    elif ShoppingItems.get(item) is None:
        notfoundSlist = input('''
    Item code was not found in the shopping list.
    1. Try again
    2. Return to shopping list
    3. Return to item options
        
    Choice: ''')
        if notfoundSlist == '1':
            return addItem()
        elif notfoundSlist == '2':
            return checkShop()
        elif notfoundSlist == '3':
            return ItemChoices()
        else:
            print('\n       You did not make a valid selection, please try again')


def removeItem():
    item = input('Enter the item you wish to add to the shopping list: ')
    Shopping_List2.remove(Shopping_List1)
    print(item + ' has been removed to the shopping list')


# def clearListCI():


def clearListFully():
    Shopping_List1.clear()
    Shopping_List2.clear()
    print('Your shopping list has been fully cleared of items.')

def checkout():
    total = 0
    for item in shopping_list:
        print(item)
        total += (float(item[1]) * float(item[2]))

    print(f" ${total}")

mainMenu()
```

Result when checking out:

```
                        --- SHOPPING MENU ---
    
    Select a number for the action you would like to do
    
    1. Check shop
    2. Check shopping list
    3. Check-out
    4. Leave
    
    Choice: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ameerul24\Downloads\mainproject1.py", line 404, in <module>
    mainMenu()
  File "C:\Users\Ameerul24\Downloads\mainproject1.py", line 17, in mainMenu
    checkShop()
  File "C:\Users\Ameerul24\Downloads\mainproject1.py", line 86, in checkShop
    ItemChoices()
  File "C:\Users\Ameerul24\Downloads\mainproject1.py", line 183, in ItemChoices
    addItem()
  File "C:\Users\Ameerul24\Downloads\mainproject1.py", line 278, in addItem
    return addItem()
  File "C:\Users\Ameerul24\Downloads\mainproject1.py", line 316, in addItem
    return mainMenu()
  File "C:\Users\Ameerul24\Downloads\mainproject1.py", line 25, in mainMenu
    checkout()
  File "C:\Users\Ameerul24\Downloads\mainproject1.py", line 398, in checkout
    for item in shopping_list:
NameError: name 'shopping_list' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Shopping_List1'?
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I am conversing with the same person as I had analyzed this program in an earlier stage and offered up some suggestions.  In testing out this iteration of the program, I can offer up a couple of suggestions regarding the issues you mentioned.  First, regarding listing prices after adding items, I revised the "displayList" function as follows:

```
def displayList():
    z = 0
    print('---------------------------------------')
    for itm in Shopping_List2:
        z = z + 1
        print(z,")", itm[0], itm[1])
    #SL1 = Shopping_List2[::3]
    #print('\nYour items:', *SL1, sep='\n- ')
    print('\nItem(s) in shopping list:', len(Shopping_List2))
    print('---------------------------------------')
```

Regarding the issue with the checkout function, the "shopping_list" variable actually was commented out.  The program probably would need to use the "Shopping_List2" list for this function as in the following code snippet.

```
def checkout():
    total = 0
    for item in Shopping_List2:
        print(item[0], '\t', item[1])
        total += (float(item[1]))

    print(f"Total:\t ${total}")
```

And to address you last comment about removing an item from the list, activated the "clearListCI()" function adding in the following code.

```
def clearListCI():
    while(1):
        displayList()
        y = input("Enter item you wish to remove or enter x to leave without removal ")
        if y == 'x':
            break
        try:
            Shopping_List2.pop(int(y) - 1)
        except:
            print("An invalid line was entered - please reenter your choice")
```

That seemed to provide the functionality needed for the item removal.

Using those tweaks, I was able to see the price associated with each item on the list and produce a checkout total.  Give that try to see if that helps you progress.

Comment: I tried the codes and it works . Thank you so much for helping!  I think the person you had helped earlier could be a schoolmate of mine

Comment: I would like to ask how to remove items codes as it is the only part that doesnt work

Comment: View the updated answer above with some code for item removal.